# A mother's age is $6$ times older than her son

Tags: word-problem

> A mother's age is $6$ times older than her son, When her son's age is
>   same as the mother, the sum of their ages will be $85$. What is mother's
>   current age?

Let's start by writing the equations

$$M = 6S$$

$t$ = passed time

$$S + t = M$$

$$S + t +M+t = 85$$

Here we get

$$2M + t = 85$$

which means that

$$12S + t = 85, 12M = 85$$

However, I'm still getting incorrect answers. Can you take a look?

Comment: What makes you say that $12M=85$? Btw, there are two equalities: $M=6S$ and $12S+t=12S+[M-S]=85$. Try again.

Comment: If a is six times older than b, then $a=7b$, not $a=6b$.

Comment: Also, the son's age will never be the same as the mother, and will never be the same as the mother's age – though it will be the same as the mother's *current* age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin by substituting M in the second equation: $S + t = 6S$. Thus $t = 5S$. 
Now substitute t and M in the third equation: $S + 6S + 10S = 85 \rightarrow 17S = 85 \rightarrow S = 5$. 
And finally substitute S in the first equation: $M = 30$.
Now check $30 = 6\cdot5$ is right and $30 + 25 + 5 + 25 = 85$ is also right.

Comment: Now, I know where I'm stuck and what to think! Regards,